# Evernote Synchronization via EDAM "field-by-field merge"

Tags: synchronization, evernote

Just stumbled upon [Evernote Synchronization via EDAM](http://dev.evernote.com/media/pdf/edam-sync.pdf) while researching sync strategies. As part of the spec when there is a conflict while syncing entities, Evernote tries to perform "field-by-field" merge:

> If the existing tag has the “dirty” flag, the user has created a tag
>   in the service and in the  client with the same name while offline. 
>   Perform a field-by-field merge or report the  conflict for resolution

How does a field-by-field merge works? 
AFAIK, Evernote does not keep track of specific field updates, it just mark whole records with a "dirty" flag, what happens if there is an update from the server to one field while the client updated another one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Evernote service does not do a field-by-field merge. The document is just saying that as part of your own sync process, you could either do that or report the conflict to the user.